# List adapter null outside onCreateView() - android

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-fragments

I am working with fragments and libraries like slidingMenu, pullToRefreshListViews, and android Aquery.
In my app I want to fill up my ListView using a custom adapter with data I parse from JSON.

here's the rough code

```
public class MyFragment extends Fragment {

public MyFragment() {
    // Empty constructor required for fragment subclasses
}
    //initialize some variables here....
    PullToRefreshListView   list;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
final View rootView = inflater.inflate(//my layout xml, container, false);
aq = new AQuery(getActivity(),rootView);
list = (PullToRefreshListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.list);
asyncJson(); // this method fetches,parses json and sets adapter to the listview
return rootView;
    }
}
```

the asyncJson() method is something like this.

```
public void asyncJson(){
    aq.ajax(url, JSONArray.class, expire, new AjaxCallback<JSONArray>() {

        @Override
        public void callback(String url, JSONArray json, AjaxStatus status) {
    try{
           // fetch and parse json store data in array<List>
        }
      if(adapter == null){
                adapter = new MyAdapter(getView().getContext(),//array<list> variables);
                list.setAdapter(adapter);

                }
                else if(adapter != null){

                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                }
    }
 });
}
```

Logcat gives me null pointer exception at  `list.setAdapter(adapter);` this line. I have no syntax errors.
Is this because of the context I pass to the adapter I tried just getActivity() but that didn't work either
is the list null or the adapter? :0
what am I doing wrong?

Thanks! **[Logcat Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NM52s.jpg)**

app project files: https://www.dropbox.com/s/9sa1l8wm4rnmnew/stackoverflow.zip

Comment: First of all check if list variable isn't null before calling asyncJson() method (in onCreateView()).

NullPointerException means that list is null (not adapter).

Comment: list != null  this condition appeared true before calling asyncJson(), so yeah list is not null

Comment: If the NullPointerException is in this line... the list is null, 100%. So double check. Make sure that you have defined in "//my layout xml" a view PullToRefreshListView with id "android:id="@+id/list". Are you inflating the correct xml? Is it the one with the PullToRefreshListView in it?

Comment: yes I just double checked just now everything seems just fine, also if the list has to be null it could be null before calling asyncJson() but its not, so is there something wrong going in the method?

Comment: check OP for logcat image

Comment: So where it is crashing inside the PullToRefresh library ... okok

Comment: know the fix? struggling since 2 days for this problem until I posted the question

Comment: Are you using Footers or Headers on your listView? Try to inflate the rootView like that... inflater.inflate(R.layout.<namelayout>, null);

Comment: yeah before I set the adapter i set a header, listview.getRefreshableView().addheader(headerView);

Comment: also,I tried this code on an Activity not a fragment and it seems to work as it is supposes to work

Comment: and get your header like this ... View header = View.inflate(this, R.layout.header_layout, null); to add it later to the listview

Comment: No answer accepted? Why?

Answer (score 0):

It's mostly your `Context` that's giving you the `NullPointerException`.

Try passing a `Context` to your fragment via the constructor and use it in the adapter.

```
private Context ctx;

  public MyFragment(Context ctx) {
    this.ctx = ctx;
}
```

And initialize the adapter like this:

```
adapter = new MyAdapter(ctx, array<list> variables);
```

Comment: "Avoid non-default constructors in fragments: use a default constructor plus Fragment#setArguments(Bundle) instead"-the lint error I get...   I have two constructors now one with the context argument and without any arguments

Comment: You could have two constructors.

Comment: Use this constructor to initialize the instance called from `slidingMenu`

Comment: check this image http://i.imgur.com/evATfFB.jpg?1 .... and also check edit in OP for logcat image

Comment: in sliding menu class i have...Fragment latestfragment = new LatestFragment(getApplicationContext()); FragmentTransaction ft1 = fm.beginTransaction(); 
      ft1.replace(R.id.content_frame, latestfragment).commit();

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are using this library ...

https://github.com/chrisbanes/Android-PullToRefresh

Dowload it and you need to import the following and add it as dependency on our project.

PullToRefreshListFragment
library

I modify the project that I download from the link on your comment. You can download it from here:

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/33565803/StackOverFlowExamples/chrisbanes%20-%20Android-PullToRefresh-master-plusHeader.zip

I am gonna write the code as well so we dont depends of this link on this answer ;). So we have only one class call MainActivity that extends from FragmentActivity.

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity implements PullToRefreshBase.OnRefreshListener<ListView> {

FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
private PullToRefreshListFragment mPullRefreshListFragment;

private PullToRefreshListView mPullRefreshListView;
private ListView mActualListView;

private String[] mStrings = {"Abbaye de Belloc", "Abbaye du Mont des Cats", "Abertam", "Abondance", "Ackawi",
        "Acorn", "Adelost", "Affidelice au Chablis", "Afuega'l Pitu", "Airag", "Airedale", "Aisy Cendre",
        "Allgauer Emmentaler", "Abbaye de Belloc", "Abbaye du Mont des Cats", "Abertam", "Abondance", "Ackawi",
        "Acorn", "Adelost", "Affidelice au Chablis", "Afuega'l Pitu", "Airag", "Airedale", "Aisy Cendre",
        "Allgauer Emmentaler"};

private LinkedList<String> mListItems;
private ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // sliding menu implementation
    /*final SlidingMenu menu = new SlidingMenu(this);
    menu.setMode(SlidingMenu.LEFT);
    menu.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);
    menu.setShadowWidthRes(R.dimen.shadow_width);
    menu.setShadowDrawable(R.drawable.shadow);
    menu.setBehindOffsetRes(R.dimen.slidingmenu_offset);
    menu.setFadeDegree(0.35f);
    menu.attachToActivity(this, SlidingMenu.SLIDING_CONTENT);
    menu.setMenu(R.layout.menu);*/

    // event handlers come after slidingmenu

    mPullRefreshListFragment = (PullToRefreshListFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.frag_ptr_list);

    //aq = new AQuery(getActivity(),mPullToRefreshListFragment.getView());

    /*mPullRefreshListView.setOnScrollListener(new EndlessScrollListener();*/


    mPullRefreshListView = mPullRefreshListFragment.getPullToRefreshListView();

    // Set a listener to be invoked when the list should be refreshed.
    mPullRefreshListView.setOnRefreshListener(this);


    // You can also just use mPullRefreshListFragment.getListView()
    mActualListView = mPullRefreshListView.getRefreshableView();


    mListItems = new LinkedList<String>();
    mListItems.addAll(Arrays.asList(mStrings));
    mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mListItems);

    View headerView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.list_header, null);
    mActualListView.addHeaderView(headerView);
    mActualListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    mPullRefreshListFragment.setListShown(true);
    /*asyncJson(1,expire);*/

}

public void asyncJson(int page, final long expire) {
    // GET JSON FROM THE WEB AND PARSE IT
    // ALSO STORE DATA IN ARRAY LIST VARIABLES

    if (expire == -1) {
        mPullRefreshListView.onRefreshComplete();
    }

    //if(pg == 1 && expire !=-1){

        //If you wanna add a header at this point, do it like this
        View headerView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.list_header, null);
        mActualListView.addHeaderView(headerView);
        // DO SOMETHING
    //}

    //Just notify the changes because the adapter do exist
    mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onRefresh(PullToRefreshBase<ListView> refreshView) {
    // Do work to refresh the list here.
    new GetDataTask().execute();
}


private class GetDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String[]> {

    @Override
    protected String[] doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // Simulates a background job.
        try {
            Thread.sleep(4000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
        return mStrings;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String[] result) {
        mListItems.addFirst("Added after refresh...");
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        // Call onRefreshComplete when the list has been refreshed.
        mPullRefreshListView.onRefreshComplete();

        super.onPostExecute(result);
    }
  }
}
```

This are the layouts we have :

activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >


     <fragment
             android:id="@+id/frag_ptr_list"
             android:name="com.handmark.pulltorefresh.extras.listfragment.PullToRefreshListFragment"
             android:layout_width="match_parent"
             android:layout_height="match_parent" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

list_row.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

list_header.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="#4a2">

<TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="My Header"
        android:textColor="#fff"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: ok so I removed the headerview and everything works perfectly, so interpreting what you said there's a conflict between pulltorefresh and headerview when used inside fragments,  I tried the code in your answer, imported PullToRefreshListFragment as library to my project and started implementing as per your answer but I didnt understand. as I am using framelayouts to switch fragments. to get a clear idea of my project I have a download link with very clear and precise code https://www.dropbox.com/s/9sa1l8wm4rnmnew/stackoverflow.zip

Comment: I have just modified my answer, you can download the project and I wrote the code  as well in case we have problems with the link on the future. Do not hesitate asking any doubt ;)